# models.py order of the models gives NameError: name 'Category/Post' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django so this is probably a dumb question but,

when I put the class Category model above the class Post model I get an

```
NameError: name 'Post' is not defined error.
```

but when I try to put class Category model underneath the Post model (as in the code here) I get

```
categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
NameError: name 'Category' is not defined error.
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  #if is deleted than delete their posts 
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    tags = TaggableManager()
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_posts')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)


    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})



class Category(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="categories") 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Comment, Category #, Konum
# Register your models here.


admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(Comment)
admin.site.register(Category)

#admin.site.register(Konum)
```

---

some of the code

```
<form method="GET" action=".">

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <select id="category" class="form-control" name="category">
                  <option selected>Choose...</option>
                  {% for cat in categories %}
                  <option value="{{ cat }}">{{ cat }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
                </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>

    </form>
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        "posts": Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def filter(request):
    qs = Post.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    id_exact_query = request.GET.get('id_exact')
    title_or_author_query = request.GET.get('title_or_author')
    category = request.GET.get('category')
    
    if is_valid_queryparam(category) and category != 'Choose...':
      qs = qs.filter(categories__name=category)


    context = {
        'posts': qs,
        'categories': Category.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 199



class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 199

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(author = user).order_by('-date_posted')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from .import views
from .views import PostListView, PostDetailView, PostCreateView, PostUpdateView, PostDeleteView, UserPostListView, TagIndexView, LikeView  #, LocationPostListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name="blog-home"), #has a empty strting bc its already processed blog part in main urls
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name="user-posts"),
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #path('location/<str:loc>', LocationPostListView.as_view(), name="location-posts"),
   #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),#pk means primary key like post 1 post 2 etc
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('about/', views.about, name="blog-about"),
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    path('tag/<slug:slug>/', TagIndexView.as_view(), name='tagged'),
    path('like/<int:pk>', LikeView, name='like_post'),
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - NameError: name 'Post' is not defined in many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054749/django-nameerror-name-post-is-not-defined-in-many-to-many-relationship)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a string literal to specify the model name of a model that still needs to be defined, so you can use `ManyToManyField('Category')` or `ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)` for example to refer to models not yet defined:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    tags = TaggableManager()
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODELS, related_name='liked_posts')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category')
```

It however does not seem to make much sense that a `Category` has a `ForeignKey` to a post: that would mean that a `Category` links to *exactly* one `Post` record?

You can for example use a `ListView` with:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 199

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        if self.request.GET.get('category'):
            return qs.filter(categories__name=self.request.GET['category'])
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: i'm actually trying to show all the posts that are linked to a category. for example when i create a post i wanna enter a category for example "coding" and when i chose that category in the homepage it will show me all the posts that has link to that category.

Comment: @FurkanKalaycıoğlu: well if you define a `ManyToManyField` in Django you can query it in both directions. So if you have a `Category` object `cat` for example, you can get all related `Post` objects with `cat.post_set.all()`. There is thus no need to define a `ForeignKey` in `Category`.

Comment: @FurkanKalaycıoğlu: you already do: by defining a `ManyToManyField` it means that a `Post` is related to zero, one, or many `Category`s, and a `Category` is linked to zero, one or more `Post`s. It thus immediately works in *both* directions.

Comment: ok but when i create a post from admin section i chose a category for it and when i look up the categories in admin section i dont see any posts linked to them.

Comment: @FurkanKalaycıoğlu: that is because the *form* will only work in the model you define the `ManyToManyField` in, but you thus can query for example in a `ListView` to get all `Post`s that belong to a certain `Category`.

Comment: @FurkanKalaycıoğlu: but you can for example add `'categories__name'` in the `search_fields` to search `Post`s by category name.

Comment: i'm extremely confused haha. sorry to take your time but can i just show my code? i'm actually doing a query search yet still not working

Comment: @FurkanKalaycıoğlu: you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70897710/edit) the question.

Comment: i just added an answer i guess im bad at using stackoverflow as well lol

Comment: @FurkanKalaycıoğlu: in your `filter` view, you use a `Journal`, not a `Post`? Exactly *what* view are you using to render the template?

Comment: i've fixed that as Post still same bug tho

Comment: @FurkanKalaycıoğlu: but I don't see `home` or `filter` being used at all in the `urls.py`.

Comment: oh right...  sorry i was just following some blogs and tutorials and trying to make sense.

Comment: how exactly can i use filter in urls?

Comment: @FurkanKalaycıoğlu: you can pass the categories to the template by overriding `get_context_data`, and filter with `get_queryset`, see update.

Comment: @FurkanKalaycıoğlu It sounds like Willem answered your original question about an error you were getting. If you have additional problems, you should post a new question. You may want to include a link to this question to help provide context.

Comment: even though I still couldn't understand thank you so much I'll figure it out somehow haha. you're awesome man thanks for helping me out with such a simple thing haha.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem if it's not too much to ask can you write that line for me?( for to do: "you can pass the categories to the template by overriding get_context_data, and filter with get_queryset, see update." ) if it's something long just nevermind lol.

Comment: @FurkanKalaycıoğlu: It's already in the updated answer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem    it says  'QuerySet' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @FurkanKalaycıoğlu: you don't use `sorted` or anything like that?